# Run python in background from other python program and continue

Tags: python, python-3.x, background, subprocess, os.system

How to run a python program in between another python program

```
os.system(r'pythonw.exe D:\text.py')
```

I have tried this but it had pause execution between the main program
and also tried

```
subprocess.run(r'pythonw.exe D:\text.py')
```

suppose I have program text.py which notify me every hour
I have main program i.e.

```
code...
os.system(r'pythonw.exe D:\text.py')
code...
print("hello world")
```

my command should run text.py in the background and execute the following code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python Library named "Soldier". This is very easy to use and implement.
https://pypi.org/project/soldier

```
import soldier

firefox_process = soldier.run('firefox', background=True)
firefox_process.pid
```